# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 21 >= 21

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I got the below error message.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 21 >= 21
        at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)
        at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:277)
        at com.vanuston.medeil.uitables.PurchaseTable.createTable(PurchaseTable.java:182)
        at com.vanuston.medeil.ui.Purchase.applyDefaults$(Purchase.fx:130)
```

on the third line of the below code.

```
jTable.removeColumn(jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(19));
jTable.removeColumn(jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(20));
jTable.removeColumn(jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(21));
jTable.removeColumn(jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(22));
```

I already added the 21st and 22nd column to the `DefaultTableModel`.

```
Vector cols = new Vector();
    Vector data = new Vector();
    int len = colName.length;
    System.out.println("col length " + len);
    for (int i = 0; i < initRow; i++) {
        Vector c = new Vector();
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            if (j == 19 && j == 20) {
                c.addElement(Boolean.FALSE);
            } else {
                c.addElement(null);
            }
        }
        data.addElement(c);
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < len; n++) {
        cols.addElement(colName[n]);
        System.out.println(colName[n]);
    }
    try {
        jTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(data, cols) {

            Class[] type = types;
            boolean[] canEditCol = canEditCols;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return type[columnIndex];
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEditCol[columnIndex];
            }

        });
```

But I don't know, what's the reason for showing `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

Comment: can you print the size of that model right before running that line?

Comment: You are removing column on each line so I guess they are getting reindexed.

Comment: `int len = colName.length;sysout(len);` output 23

Comment: Remove them in reverse order.

Comment: @Tunaki then how i remove those 4 cols? Through loop?

Comment: you can remove them by iterating `jTable.removeColumn(jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(19)); ` four times

Comment: @NamanGala good idea, let me try..

Comment: @NamanGala Tunaki, works., thanks. Are you willing to post answer?

Comment: @Tunaki kindly convert your comment into answer, as you pointed out it first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you call [`JTable.removeColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#removeColumn-javax.swing.table.TableColumn-), each column of the array of columns is getting reindexed. For example, when element 0 is removed, the element that was at index 1 is now reindexed at index 0.

You need to remove those columns in reverse order, so that this reindexing doesn't happen:

```
jTable.removeColumn(jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(22));
jTable.removeColumn(jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(21));
jTable.removeColumn(jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(20));
jTable.removeColumn(jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(19));
```

You could also call 4 times the following line:

```
jTable.removeColumn(jTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(19));
```

since at each call `i`, column `19 + i` will become column 19.

Comment: plus one, but XxxTableModel returns always all ..., column is removed only from JTables view, reason for (you have to notice to OP about) convert index from view to model :-), there are two methods row (sorting, filtering) and column (columns are reorderer or removed from view only)